# First three items of navigation anchor not functioning properly

Tags: html, css

My web page is at http://www.sarahjanetrading.com/js/j/index.html.

In the navigation, when I hover or want to click on the first three navigation
items, they don't function properly. The whole of the area of the first three navigation items
are not clickable. The rest of the navigation items are working properly.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: That link does not work.  Can you post all of the relevant code in this question so that this question will be useful to future visitors?

Answer (score 1):

Your logo is appearing over the top of the 3 items

If you reduce the height of the logo you can select the items

Answer (score 0):

The logo (*< div class="logo">*) is above the first 3 elements, try resizing it.

```
.logo {
height: 45px;
}
```

Firebug is quite good to find these problems

Answer (score 0):

As Curt said `Your logo is appearing over the top of the 3 items` . So, here is the solution just give `z-index` to your `ul#nav` DIV.

Like this:

```
ul#nav {
    margin-left: 25px;
    position: relative;
    top: 22px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```